# WordPress Multisite - Load users using custom query

Tags: multisite, users

I have a basic custom query in WordPRess that loads all the users as shown in the following.

`SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM " . $wpdb->users . " as users`

How do I modify it so that I can load users separately from each blog in multisite network?

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Why do not use the default functions include switch_to_blog()?

Comment: You mean calling switch_to_blog() and then executing this query will work?

Comment: No. I mean `switch_to_blog()` and then the custom function/class `WP_User_Query` to get users from each site. Alternative is the wrapper `get_users()` to get all users from a site.

Comment: Thanks for the update. At the moment we are using custom query as its not easy to implement the custom conditions we have with WP_User_Query. I gave the most simple query. We add lot more conditions to this query. At this stage, its not posible to use WP_User_Query or get_users function. Is there any other way to achive this with custom query?

Comment: Yes, a custom query is also possible. You find the code in the fuction geht_users(), is the same query ason your goal.

Comment: I don't have one in front of me, but don't multi-site installations share a user table for all sites? Do you mean only users that have a role on a given blog? That's probably just where-exists rows in the wp_usermeta table for that blog with the given user ID.

Answer (score 3):

In following to my comments on the question the follow examples for a solution.

### Default Function

WordPress have the function `get_users` to get all users for each site, works on single or multisite area. But to get all users from each site in Multisite network is the switch to each site important. The follow example demonstrate this.

```
// Multisite
// get sites in the Multisite network
$sites = wp_get_sites();
// Switch in each Site
foreach( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
    // Get Users of each site
    var_dump( count( get_users() ) );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

The code above get count (`count()`) all users in each site of the network.

If you are in a single site of the network, then is the function `get_users()` enough to get all users of this site. The function use the WordPress global `$GLOBALS['blog_id']` to identifier the site on his ID.

### Alternative for custom requirements

If the function is not helpful, use the `WP_User_Query` for your requirements.
The class give you a lot of possibilities to get user data in each site. Also use the helping hands of `switch_to_blog()` to switch on each site of the Multisite.
See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for helpful hints, parameters and example source.

Small hint, the function `get_users` is a wrapper to use it easy of the `WP_User_Query`-class.

### Hints for Multisite

#### Grabbing Data From Another Blog in a Network

Getting data from another blog on the same multisite install can be done. Some people use SQL commands to do this, but this can be slow, and error prone.

Although it's an inherently expensive operation, you can make use of switch_to_blog and `restore_current_blog` to make it easier, while using the standard WordPress APIs.

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
// Do something
restore_current_blog();
```

`restore_current_blog` undos the last call to `switch_to_blog`, but only by one step, the calls are not nestable, so always call `restore_current_blog` before calling `switch_to_blog` again.

#### Large Network

Listing blogs in a network is possible, but it's an expensive thing to do.
On default is the WordPress count on 10.000 sites for a network. If you will change this value, see the source below.

```
add_filter( 'wp_is_large_network', function( $is_large, $type, $count ) {

    if ( ! $is_large )
        return $is_large;

    // $type can be 'sites' or 'users'
    if ( 'sites' !== $type )
        return $is_large;

    // Default is 10000, we add one 0
    return $count > 100000;
}, 10, 3 );
```

It can be done using the `wp_get_sites( $args )` function, available since version 3.7 of WordPress. The function accepts an array of arguments specifying the kind of sites you are looking for.

The limit of this function is on 100 sites. If you network is bigger, then you must change this value via parameters on the function.

#### Cache

The function `wp_get_sites( $args )` is since 3.7 inside the core, but haven't a cache. If you use this often, transform the result in a cache, like `WP_Cache` or Transients.

It is also a good idea to cache the `get_users()` result, much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Let me repeat what the comments are urging: Find a way to do this with the built in objects in WordPress.

However, assuming you really, truly can't use a standard user query, and must use your custom query, you can at least leverage other, built-in WordPress functions to find the blogs to which each user has been assigned a permission.

It's ugly to do so. It's complicated to do so. But it can be done.

**Note** I have not tested this code because I do not have WP set up for multiuser, but it should work, unless your install is considered a large network by `wp_is_large_network`.

```
//not sure how you are getting these user rows; I would do it this way, getting a results set for iteration
global $wpdb;
$users_rs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT users FROM " . $wpdb->users . " AS users" ) );

//step 1: We need a list of all sites in this WPMU install
$sites = wp_get_sites();

/* step 2: we need to create an array to hold the users of each blog
* outermost array: site IDs; middle array: blog IDs; inner array: users for each blog
* technically we don't need to declare as an array but this makes it self-documenting in later code
* ideally we would make this an object but let's not get carried away */
$user_list_by_blog = array( array( array() ) );

/* step 3: add blogs to $user_list_by_blog
* first, we need to know which site we are currently on
* so we start with a dummy value for a iteration variable 
* in theory wp_get_sites will be ordered by sites, then blogs
* at least, we hope it's that way or this code won't work */
$current_site = -1;

//ok, now we can walk the sites and add the blogs for each site to our master list
foreach( $sites as $site ) {
    if( $current_site != $site[ 'site_id' ] ) {
        $current_site = $site[ 'site_id' ] );
    }
    $user_list_by_blog[ $current_site ][] = $site[ 'blog_id' ];
}

/* step 4: we're ready to add users to the master list created above
* now we walk the results set from the custom query
* this thing is a bear, but it's as efficient as I can think to make it. */
foreach( $users_rs as $user ) {
    //get the sites and blogs to which the user with that ID has access
    $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user->ID );

    //walk that result
    foreach( $user_blogs as $user_blog ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $user_list_by_blog ); $i++ ) {
            if( $user_list_by_blog[ $i ] == $user_blog->site_id ) {
                //we have the right site, now let's find the right blog
                for( $x = 0; $x < count( $user_list_by_blog[ $i ] ); $x++ ) {
                    if( $user_list_by_blog[ $i ][ $x ] == $user_blog->blog_id ) {
                        //we have the right blog, add the user id
                        $user_list_by_blog[ $i ][ $x ][] = $user->ID;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/* we now have, in $user_list_by_blog, a list of users by site and by blog
* this is a record dump to show you the structure
* wrap it in <pre> tags to make it pretty, if you like */
var_dump( $user_list_by_blog );
```

Did I mention what a terrible way of going about your desired end this code proves? Well, in case I didn't: *This is a terrible way of going about things.* Try to find a way to do what you want with WordPress' built-in functions. Really. Seriously. Try. Then try harder. Then try even harder. Because this isn't a good idea, this code I just wrote.